# How to generate a module with empty res files

Tags: android, kotlin, android-multi-module

Whenever I'm creating a new module I find myself annoyed that it does not come with a generated res directory for colors, strings etc. It is quite annoying that I have to create it within every feature-module and also I cannot find a way to create colors.xml (both dark and normal, you cannot create a file with the same name twice), is there any way to spin up a module with those empty files? (or at least add both colors (night) and normal?)

Comment: Write a script in your favorite scripting language to add whatever you want to the module.

Comment: How can I add both of the color resources?

Comment: Create XML file(s) that contain your resources. Store them somewhere on your computer. In your script, copy the files into the desired directory (e.g., `cp` command on macOS and Linux).